# Wave velocity (R)LC circuits.

Tags: electricity, waves, electric-circuits

I'm attempting to simulate some fluid like mechanics using circuits. Specifically wave propagation. I am attempting to measure the wave propagation velocity using an oscilloscope on the circuit below, L1 = L2 = L3 and C1 = C2. R1 is the characteristic impedance:

[image: Wave Circuit]

I understand the theory behind it and can derive the wave equation with v = 1/Sqrt[LC] but I'm wondering how precisely to measure it since a) the oscilloscope is showing the time domain, b) distance here is discrete values (LC group 1, LC group 2) etc... I am able to see the phase shift when measuring the voltage after L1, L2 and L3.

Thanks